# android app root or system privileges

Tags: android, system, root, su

I am trying to build an android app that can access /data dir (for example) without parsing the output of a command ran on a shell after doing su.

I mean, after researching a lot, and looking also in the code of some root explorers, what they do when they need root perms is parsing the output of a command after doing su.

What I want is doing something like:

```
File file = new File("/data");
File[] files = file.listFiles();// get the list array of file
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    File fileItem = files[i];
    System.out.println("FILE NAME: "+fileItem.getName().toString()) {
}
```

For achieving this I think that the application process must be running as root from the begining of the execution.

I tried to run the APP from the shell after doing su this way:

```
$su
#am start -n com.example.test/.ui.Activity
```

But its the same after looking at the output of the ps command I see that the application is running as user "u0_a110" and not root.

Also I tried with the parameter --user 0 and --user 1000, with the same results... I think that the dalvik virtual machine drops the privileges from the parent process.

I also tried to convert the app to a system app moving it to /system/priv-app with the same results, ( the running user of the app its not root and also not system )

May be with:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

In the manifest the application runs as the user system at least, I tried to run that way the app and also placed in /system/priv-app and the phone didn't finish booting.

I think that error its because the app needs to be signed with the system key from the manufacturer.

Its possible to run some android app as root or at least system ?

I know that if I cross compile a linux app for ARM (or the architecture of the phone) and run that app in the shell as root, that app will have root access, but, is that the only way? I want to achieve that with an android java app.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way for a java app to achive this. Even assign system uid to the app and sign it with platform certification, it still can't gain root privilege. The idea of systemuid is to access some system level apis such as controlling the airplane mode, getting framebuffer, force-stopping package etc, but not controlling the filesystem with root privilege.

Comment: If you look at the output of: ps | grep system, you see a lot of android apps that run as system user, some of them I nearly sure that are java apps. like com.android.settings

Comment: @Mario Rial: This may be the case on older devices. But on a current Android 5 devices only deamons are running with system or root permissions.

Comment: My test device is an android 4.4.2, what you mean with daemon? an android system service or a regular linux daemon? so in current android versions the only way to run an app as root or at least system is doing that compiling a regular linux app for android and run it as root?

Comment: Java app can run as system user('android.uid.system' + 'platform certification' = 'system user', this is the highest privilege a java app can get). But the system user does not have root privilege. android.os.Process defined ROOT_UID=0, SYSTEM_UID=1000, so there's no way for a java app to run as root. The root user processes of the 'ps | grep root' are binary programs in /system/bin/ directory.